# Pass Type to Generic Action from View MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm doing some refactoring and I realized I had some badly repeated code going on. Old Code:

```
public JsonResult GetResult(InheritType type)
{
    if(type == InheritType.TypeOne){
        var iqueryable = Session.Query<TypeOneInherit>()
        //34 lines of repeated code
    }else if(type == InheritType.TypeTwo){
        var iqueryable = Session.Query<TypeTwoInherit>()
        //34 lines of repeated code
    }else if(type == InheritType.TypeThree){
        var iqueryable = Session.Query<TypeThreeInherit>()
        //34 lines of repeated code
    }
}
```

I replaced that with the following:

```
public JsonResult GetResult(InheritType type){
    switch(type){
        case type.TypeOne:
            return GetResultGeneric<TypeOneInherit>
        case type.TypeTwo:
            return GetResultGeneric<TypeTwoInherit>
        case type.TypeThree:
            return GetResultGeneric<TypeThreeInherit>
    }
}

public JsonResult GetResultGeneric<T>(InheritType type) where T : Base
{
        var iqueryable = Session.Query<T>()
        //34 lines of non repeated code

}
```

What I'd like to do is get rid of the GetResult method completely. Right now my action looks like this:

```
@Url.Action("GetResult", "ResultController", new { type = InheritType.TypeOne })
```

The action is being set in javascript to be used as the url for a JQGrid.
Instead of passing in the enum value, I'd like to be able to just pass the type so I can bypass an if block or switch statement. Is there any way of doing this? (I'd like to have just a bit cleaner code. Of course if there's a much better way of doing this I'm down with that too. Also, ignore the fact that I left out a lot of returns, they should be implied in the comments, they're there in my working code I promise.)
Thanks internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one SelectedType on your MVC code and send it as an object then you can execute your generic method like this:

```
public JsonResult GetResult(InheritType type){
    typeof(yourClass)
          .GetMethod("GetResultGeneric")
          .MakeGenericMethod(type.SelectedType.GetType())
          .Invoke(yourClass, new object[] {type});


}
```